# libuv error - uninitialized stream

Tags: libuv

I am trying to use libuv to send some data. The client connects to the server, the server accepts the connection, then the client attempts to write using uv_write (the printf is output so I know it's getting this far). The result is

```
 uv_write2: Assertion `(stream->type == UV_TCP || stream->type == UV_NAMED_PIPE || stream->type == UV_TTY) && "uv_write (unix) does not yet support other types of streams"' failed.
```

Which makes me think the stream must not be initialized. Code is below, what am I doing wrong?

```
void OnConnectToServer(uv_connect_t *client, int status) 
{
    if (status < 0) 
    {
        return;
    }

    printf( "Client attempt write\n" );

    write_req_t *req = (write_req_t*) malloc(sizeof(write_req_t));
    req->buf = uv_buf_init( (char*) malloc(1), 1 );     
    (req->buf.base)[0] = '0';
    uv_write((uv_write_t*) req, client->handle, &req->buf, 1, OnWrite); 
}

void SendData( uv_async_t*sd )
{
    uv_tcp_t client;
    uv_tcp_init(loop, &client);
    uv_connect_t* connect = (uv_connect_t*)malloc(sizeof(uv_connect_t));
    struct sockaddr_in dest;
    uv_ip4_addr("192.168.20.3", PORT, &dest);
    uv_tcp_connect(connect, &client, (const struct sockaddr*)&dest, OnConnectToServer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`uv_write_t` is the right struct, but you can't use `req->buf` which is a private field. You must declare a new variable like so:

```c
uv_write_t *req = (uv_write_t*) malloc(sizeof(uv_write_t));
uv_buf_t buf = uv_buf_init( (char*) malloc(1), 1 );
buf.base[0] = '0';
uv_write(req, client->handle, &buf, 1, OnWrite);
```